# How to set proxy for individual requests in Apache HttpClient 5?

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

I would like to configure an HTTP proxy for some individual requests and not for others, using **Apache HttpClient 5**.  However it looks like `RequestConfig.Builder.setProxy()` is [deprecated](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html#setProxy-org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpHost-).  The javadoc suggests using `HttpRoutePlanner`, but it looks like this operates at the global `HttpClient` level, not at the request level.

Is there a way in HttpClient 5 to configure the proxy at the request level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the arguments to `HttpRoutePlanner`'s `determineRoute` method is the `HttpContext`. You can use that, especially if you extend `DefaultRoutePlanner` and override its `determineProxy` method, because this is part of the (current) `determineRoute` implementation:

```java
HttpHost proxy = config.getProxy();
if (proxy == null) {
    proxy = determineProxy(host, context);
}
```

For each request you can now explicitly create an `HttpContext`, set the proxy host as attribute, and then use your custom `DefaultRoutePlanner` sub class to extract that proxy from the `HttpContext`.

That does mean you need to explicitly configure the proxy for each request separately though.